# Javascript : Uncheck a different checkbox when one checkbox is Unchecked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I know its kinda duplicate , my am trying to do this in a different way and thus re-posting this question.

What am trying to achieve is , when someone "Un-Check" the OSPF Checkbox .. the Passive Interface Check should also get "Uncheched" automatically.  I'm trying to debug why UnChecked is not working, but no luck.  Below is my code.

```
OSPF <input type="checkbox" name="ospfen" id="ospfen_1" onclick="if(this.unchecked){document.getElementById('ospfpassive_1').checked=false;}">&nbsp; Passive Interface<input type="checkbox" name="ospfpassive" id="ospfpassive_1" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById('ospfen_1').checked=true;}"> <br />
```

I also wanted if someone check the Passive Interface checkbox...the OSPF should get checked and this part of the code is working fine.  Only "Un-Check" is not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check my answer. You can also separate your javascript code from HTML, it will be cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `unchecked` does not exists. So use check `checked` :)

```
OSPF <input type="checkbox" name="ospfen" id="ospfen_1" onchange="if(!this.checked){document.getElementById('ospfpassive_1').checked=false;}">

Passive Interface <input type="checkbox" name="ospfpassive" id="ospfpassive_1" onchange="if(this.checked){document.getElementById('ospfen_1').checked=true;}"> <br />
```

Here is a working example :

https://jsfiddle.net/0mn3mprv/

Comment: I was not aware uncheck property was not there....what I did few sec back to make it working is below ..is for sure ugly and yours is good. thanks                                                                                           OSPF <input type="checkbox" name="ospfen" id="ospfen_1" onclick="if(document.getElementById('ospfen_1').checked==false)
   {document.getElementById('ospfpassive_1').checked=false;}">&nbsp; Passive Interface<input type="checkbox" name="ospfpassive" id="ospfpassive_1" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById('ospfen_1').checked=true;}"> <br />

Answer (score 1):

There's no 'unchecked' property.

Use:

```
!this.checked
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an easier way to approach it

onclick="document.getElementById('ospfpassive_1').checked = !this.checked;"

this way the other check box's checked property is always the opposite

Comment: I dont want always the opposite.  What I need is ...If OSPF is selected ...Passive "Can" be selected . If  Only Passive is selected ..OSPF get selected automatically which is working.   Finally , if ospf and passive both are selected and someone unselect OSPF ....Passive get unselected ...which is broken

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes does not have a property named `unchecked`. You must verify the value the property named `checked`.

```html
OSPF 
<input type="checkbox" name="ospfen" id="ospfen_1" onclick="if(!this.checked){document.getElementById('ospfpassive_1').checked=false;}">

&nbsp; 

Passive Interface
<input type="checkbox" name="ospfpassive" id="ospfpassive_1" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById('ospfen_1').checked=true;}"> <br />
```